# maven : Failed to install metadata project Could not parse metadata maven-metadata-local.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag

Tags: java, xml, maven, installation

Got this error when I was trying to build a project which I just downloaded from SVN.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install
>   (default-install) on project : Failed to install metadata
>   project:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata
>   C:\Users.m2\project\1.0-SNAPSHOT\maven-metadata-local.xml: only
>   whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position:
>   START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I just wanted to document this error on the internet. There was no much help or I didn't search properly.

**Answer** :

Go to the the path where the `maven-metadata-local.xml` is. Delete the project folder along with the `xml` and build the project.

It worked for me!

Comment: Cool, but why does the problem happen in the first place?

Comment: Check my question. Its a scenario which I faced. Not everyone need not the same.

Comment: I do face the same scenario on some server. Though I'm able to temporarily fix it with a simular workaround, it always come back. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: We also are facing this issue on our CI and just having the manual workaround of deleting the file is not a fix. Is anyone facing this in a local environment too?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, then delete the maven-metadata-local.xml  file.

Comment: I deleted the entire m2 folder but still it is occurring

Comment: worked flawlessly for me after deleting only that project in m2 repo

Comment: @ymajoros for me this issue came while my windows shut down while the maven build was in progress. So I guess it may happen due to forceful termination in between build.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting the project folder and the maven-metadata-local.xml in the local repository solves the problem as stated by eugene-s's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024582/maven-failed-to-install-metadata-project-could-not-parse-metadata-maven-metada/26024633#26024633).

Even though the problem in the question does not seem to be caused by concurrent usage of the local maven repository, this problem often occurs in a CI environment when the various jobs use the same maven local repository system.

You can either go with the solution (by user2818782) to always user a fresh repository, or you can start using https://github.com/takari/takari-local-repository which is a replacement to the local maven repository that is safe for concurrent access.

Answer (score 7):

By adding the

***" -Dmaven.repo.local=$WORKSPACE/.repository"***

argument to your mvn install command it forces Maven to use a local private repository, instead of the central one (~/.m2/repository).

Every Maven build will start with a fresh repository, thus avoiding such conflicts. This trick does however come with the caveat that it now needs to download EvERYTHING. So expect dramatically increased network traffic (not a problem if you use a local Nexus as a mirror), and slightly longer build times.

Answer (score 3):

We got the same problem in a project right after modifying the `pom.xml` to add some plugins and configurations. 
Deleting the project folders from maven local repository cache solved it.

Answer (score 0):

## 2023 update

It seems this occure when concurrent maven build writes to the same dependency file, resulting in an additional XML tag being appended to the file.

I fixed it by editing the file directly , the file has an extra xml tag at the end of it .

**This problem has been addressed in recent Maven versions**, particularly in resolver versions greater than 1.7.x (likely Maven versions later than 3.8.x).

You can find information regarding this improvement in Maven's documentation on shared access to the local repository [here](https://maven.apache.org/resolver/local-repository.html#shared-access-to-local-repository). Despite this improvement, the issue persists in our shared cache of CI environment, possibly because some projects are still using older versions of Maven to build theirs projects.